# Elixir: DBConnection queue_target and queue_interval explained

Tags: timeout, elixir, dbconnection

I am reading [DBConnection documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.html#start_link/2-queue-config). And I don't quite understand following quote:

> Our goal is to wait at most :queue_target for a connection.
> If all connections checked out during a :queue_interval takes more than
> :queue_target, then we double the :queue_target. If checking out
> connections take longer than the new target, then we start dropping
> messages.

Could you please explain me on examples?

1. In my app I have very huge operation that is executed by periodic worker. I would like to have timeout for it 1minute, or don't have timeout at all. Which `queue_target` and `queue_interval` should I set to avoid: `Elixir.DBConnection.ConnectionError',message => <<"tcp recv: closed (the connection was closed by the pool, possibly due to a timeout or because the pool has been terminated)"`
2. In regular case I would like me queue timeout to be 5 seconds. How could I achieve this with `queue_target` and `queue_interval`?

Answer (score 3):

The timeouts you're referring to are set with the `:timeout` option in execution functions (i.e. `execute/4`), `:queue_target` and `:queue_interval` are only meant to affect the pool's ability to begin *new* requests (for requests to checkout connections from the pool), *not* requests that have already checked out connections and are already being processed.

Keep in mind that *all* attempts to checkout connections during a `:queue_interval` must take longer than `:queue_target` in order for these values to affect anything. Normally you'd test different values and monitor your database's ability to keep up in order to find optimal values for your environment.